# PDO/PHP Undefined variables

Tags: php, undefined

I have a feeling I made a syntax error on my part. Is there anything else besides a syntax error or forgetting to define a variable that would cause it?

Note: I am now getting an error stating that it is expecting a ; on the line which contains `if ($query->execute(array($user_name))) {`

```
    if (isset($_GET['username'])){
        $user_name = $_GET['user_name'];
        $dbh = connectDb(); 
        $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ?");
        if ($query->execute(array($user_name))) {
            while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $email = $row['user_email'];
                $admin = $row['user_access_level'];
                $dbusername = $row['user_name'];
            }
        }
        if ($user_name != $dbusername) {
            echo "There has been a fatal error. Please try again.";
        }
    } else echo "you need to specify a username!";
?>
    <center><h2><?php echo $dbusername; ?>'s Profile</h2><br /></center>
    <table width="350" border="3" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#000000">
        <tr><td>Username:</td><td><?php echo $user_name; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>User Level:</td><td><?php echo $userlvl; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email:</td><td><?php echo $email; ?></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Just a side note, unless your `query` method in your database code cleans strings before executing a query, your website is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: `$dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = $user_name",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` gives you an instance of PDOStatement, not an array. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

This is a small typo problem:

```
if (isset($_GET['username'])){
  $user_name = $_GET['username']; /* here you are using user_name it should be username or both should be user_name */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ?");
if ($query->execute(array($user_name))) {
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $email = $row['user_email'];
    }
}
```

You're looking for something like that. Please note I'm on my iPhone so it's hard to code, haha

Comment: @CyberizedNinja I can't see where or why it would require a ; on that line. Double check your code in your file and check everything looks right. You might have hit a key by accident before saving and uploading to your server or something